# Magento PayPal Express Uses Base Currency without Converting

Tags: php, magento, paypal

I have the currency conversion set up on my Magento store which shows the converted price in the shopping cart, however when a user clicks on PayPal Checkout, the website passes over the converted price but PayPal then displays it in the wrong currency.

For example, my base currency is GBP, if a price of an item is £100 GBP, a user can use the currency convert and say get a price of $150 USD in the shopping cart. When they click the PayPal checkout button, they'll be taken to PayPal, however they will be asked to pay £150 (GBP) instead of £100 GBP. So PayPal is using the converted price, but changing the currency.

Surely this can't be how Magento and PayPal handle payments? Is it an option that I haven't selected in the backend or does the model need editing?

My website is www.normadorothy.com.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a 3rd party plugin for currency conversion? I guess the currency converter plugin is not compatible with the Magento PayPal gateway.

Comment: It's not a third party plugin - just the standard Magento converter

Comment: Are you using PayPal Standard gateway? Try maybe with a different PayPal gateway. You can configure PayPal Express Checkout and see if Magento keeps the currency.

Comment: Hi pralthom, thanks for your help! It's Website Payments Pro which includes Express Checkout, I can't separate the two without disabling Payments Pro which would mean no credit card processing unfortunately.

Comment: So the issue was actually a currency import had failed, and all currencies where set to 1 - so no difference between any of the currencies. This means the currency on the website wasn't correct, but the amount sent to PayPal was. So £100 GBP would be displayed as $100 on the website (incorrectly).

Answer (score 0):

So the issue was actually a currency import had failed, and all currencies where set to 1 - so no difference between any of the currencies. This means the currency on the website wasn't correct, but the amount sent to PayPal was. So £100 GBP would be displayed as $100 on the website (incorrectly)